# How to disable a check like `misc-unused-using-decls` in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, clang-tidy

I have a bunch of these warnings showing up in my C++ code. I don't want to see them.

[image]

So I added the key to the list of disabled warnings. But there is no change. Visual Studio Code keeps showing me these things in the "Problems" list. How do I disable them?

[image]

Comment: what if you reload the window?

Comment: The problem persists.

Comment: It would help to see the `clang-tidy` command VSCode is running.  In Settings, change "C_Cpp: Logging Level" to "Debug", then re-run code analysis and look in the Output window (View -> Output), in the "C/C++" tab.

Comment: I get nothing in the panel. When I try to run an Analyze command, I get a popup in lower right that says: "IntelliSense-related commands cannot be executed when `C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine` is set to `disabled`." I don't remember setting that. But  I have installed the clangd extension, so I maybe it did?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem diagnosis

The issue is you have installed the [clangd extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd), which runs the `clangd` program in the background.  `clangd` embeds the `clang-tidy` functionality [(doc link)](https://clangd.llvm.org/features#clang-tidy-checks), and it runs in the background automatically, contributing problem reports to the VSCode "Problems" window.

This is different from how the [C/C++ extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) works, invoking `clang-tidy` in response to the palette command "C/C++: Run Code Analysis on Active File".  The configuration setting "C_Cpp > Code Analysis > Clang Tidy > Checks: Disabled" only affects `clang-tidy` when invoked by the C/C++ extension, not the clangd extension.

### Solution

To influence the `clang-tidy` that runs as part of `clangd`, you have to create a `.clang-tidy` file in your project directory.

For example, this `.clang-tidy` will disable `misc-unused-using-decls`:

```
---
Checks: '-misc-unused-using-decls'
```

Having created a `.clang-tidy` file like that, the next time you modify your source file (even without saving), the findings produced by that checker will disappear from the Problems window.

### A forgotten prompt?

Since the clangd extension and the C/C++ extension both provide language services, the former prompts to disable the latter upon installation with a dialog that looks like this:

[image: Prompt from clangd extension to disable intellisense]

Presumably, this prompt appeared when you added the clangd extension, and you clicked to disable Intellisense at that time, but forgot about it (understandably).  It's also far from obvious that doing so changes how `clang-tidy` runs, and thereby obviates the related settings in the "C_Cpp > Code Analysis" section, but it turns out it does.